# how to downgrade red hat version?

Tags: yum

I just upgrade my system from RHEL 6.3 to 6.4, which is announced today. Then I found some application can't work well with RHEL 6.4 so I want to downgrade to RHEL 6.3.
The yum downgrade command need a specific packages name as input. What I need is a way to totally revert to RHEL 6.3. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: What applications are you having problems with? You don't need to downgrade the distribution, you may need to revert to an older kernel or older versions of certain libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4 is just Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.0 with all updates rolled into it. "Downgrading" would mean going to 5.x. If something isn't "certified" for RHEL 6.4 it's just lagging behind, or perhaps it is incompatible with a specific update (if so, I'd be rather suspicious of a package that breaks with Red Hat's *very* conservative package update policy).

Answer (score 0):

RedHat says the correct solution is to install the appropriate kernel version, then downgrade to the previous minor release:

How to downgrade kernel and redhat-release to a previous minor version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/186763

```
# yum list kernel-2.6.32-358*
...
kernel.x86_64        2.6.32-358.23.2.el6        rhel-6.2-server-for-rhs-2.0-rpms

# yum install kernel-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6

# Reboot

# yum downgrade redhat-release
```

Confirm the downgrade:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum update --releasever=9.1
yum downgrade redhat-release
```

This worked for me for downgrading RHEL 9.2 to RHEL 9.1